# Dynamic Programming for Graph Splitting

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, divide-and-conquer

I have a graph which has edges between every vertices `i` and `j` such
that `i < j`.  I need to divide the graph into two parts such that the sum of the weight of the edges traveling from the lowest index to the highest index is minimum.  For example there is a graph of 4 vertices where each edge weight is the following

```
w(1, 2) = 100
w(1, 3) = 2
w(1, 4) = 1
w(2, 3) = 100
w(2, 4) = 100
w(3, 4) = 3
```

The solution would be `{2}, {1,3,4}`. Therefore the ans will be sum of edge 1 and 3 and edge 3 and 4 i.e. 2 + 3 = 5. We start from the lowest index vertex and move to the highest index vertex.

The algorithm I came up was a brute force i.e. considering each
combination and return the minimum of it i.e. to take one vertex in one
group or include in other which leads to complexity O(2^n).

I want to get the above problem to run in O(n^2) solution.  I did draw
a decision tree for the above problem and can see nodes being overlapped
i.e. `{1,2}, {3,4}` and `{3,4}, {1,2}` so I figured this is a
dynamic programming problem but I am not able to define the states, or
maybe it is not a DP problem.

Comment: The key to solving a dynamic programming problem is to think through your brute force solution and work out under what circumstances it calculates the answer for a combination of inputs a previous step has already considered. If you're finding it difficult to reason about, consider writing out the steps one by one until you note the repetition.

Comment: @moonshadow I did draw a decision tree and can see the nodes being overlapped i.e. in one branch of the tree the node would be (1,2) (3,4) and in the other branch (3,4)(1,2) but I am not able to understand how can I memoize the above states ?

Comment: Sorry—am I missing something here about your problem formulation? The problem you describe is the weighted Max-Cut problem, which is NP-hard in general. Your particular graph is planar, so there's a polynomial time solution—but do you have this guarantee in general? If not, you won't get far with DP.

Comment: Also—this question is probably better suited for our sister site [cs.SE] than here, because it's about computer science algorithms and theory, not programming or debugging.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Seems like this question is the weighted max-cut problem on a **complete** graph. So the graph is **not** planar in general.

Comment: @VighneshKumar There *is* a greedy algorithm that runs in O(n^2). You can then use that solution with a branch and bound implementation. Branch and bound will help the average case, but I don't think it changes the worst case O(2^n). The compromise is a hill climbing algorithm that improves upon the greedy solution, and runs for whatever time you choose.

Comment: @user3386109 Ah, I missed the word 'every'. Thanks!

Comment: @user3386109 can you let me know about the greedy algorithm which runs in O(n^2) time.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy the graph is neither complete nor planar.

Comment: Greedy algorithm: Sort the vertices by the total weight of the edges connected to the vertex, in descending order. Start with two empty sets. For each vertex, compute the cost of adding the vertex to each of the two sets. Add the vertex to the set with the lower cost. Computing the costs takes O(n) time, and that computation is done `n` times, so O(n^2) total time. In the example, the list of vertices by descending weight would be `(2,300) (3,105) (4,104) (1,103)` So vertex 2 is added to the first set, and 3 is added to the other set. Then 4 and 1 are added to the set with 3.

Comment: @user3386109 can you provide proof as to why greedy will give us the optimal each time ?

Comment: @VighneshKumar It isn't guaranteed to give an optimal solution. The greedy algorithm simply gives you a starting point for a [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) implementation, or a hill climbing algorithm.